# Accessing ubuntu files from windows

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have two computers and installed ubuntu in one computer and windows7 in one computer. I would like to access ubuntu files from windows7.

How can i access ubuntu files from windows7?

Answer (score 9):

There are several solutions you can use, like this two:

[Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16)

[Ext2Read](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

Second solution doesn't even have to be installed - you can just run .exe file and access partitions you want.

However, this solutions are 100% safe only for reading. If you need to read and write to Ubuntu partition often, you should create shared NTFS partition which you could access from both operating systems.